# PHP Syntax Error on line 1

Tags: php, html, syntax

Below is the code for a simple php file with some functions that run perfectly happily when the inside of the php tag is commented out. isLoggedIn() is a function that I know is coded correctly in the session.php file as it is used elsewhere and works.

For some weird reason, firefox console is telling me there is a syntax error on line 1:

> [00:11:56.115] SyntaxError: syntax error @ admin_script.php:1

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
include('../includes/session.php');
if(isLoggedIn() == false)
{
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Page Not Found');
}
?>


$(document).ready(function(){
/* All the JS code here for the admin page to be sent to the HTML.
Two functions, one needs to provide the sections to the "editor-sections" div and another the content to the "editor-content" div.
*/

$('button[id=exercises_button]').click(function(){
exercise_editor();
});

$('button[id=problems_button]').click(function(){
problems_editor();
});

var exercise_editor = function(){
window.alert("Exercise button clicked");
};

var problems_editor = function(){
window.alert("Problems button clicked");
};
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just to be clear, you are talking about a javascript console error?  Is this the full script (i.e. do you not have any DOCTYPE, HTML tags ,etc. )?

Comment: Could it be encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it, thank you for all your responses, but the directory was all correct and everything. I decided to re-write the small php segment, just wondering if spaces made any difference (even though I knew they wouldn't) and miraculously it worked. I believe that the location of the `heaader()` was causing the trouble as when I re-wrote it, I simply changed it to `header('Location: http://www.google.com` and no problem came about.

So very very strange, especially as the change had nothing to do with line 1. Thank you for all your responses!

Answer (score 0):

i think your directory is wrong .. if you have session file on same folder , 
do include("file.php")

let this be folder structure

-folderA
__ *|-folderB

_*__|-folderC

if you have your index file on folder A and you have session file on B or C , do include("folderA(B).php") . if you have index.php on folder B or C and your session.php on A, then do include("../folderA/session.php")

Answer (score 0):

I think your path is wrong the error message says that the error is on the line 1

SyntaxError: syntax error @ admin_script.php:1

if the file structure is

```
admin_script.php
-includes/session.php

the path is include('includes/session.php');
```

if you are in this condition

```
-folder/admin_script.php
-includes/session.php

than the correct path is include('../includes/session.php');
```